# Parse withinMiles return closest first

Tags: java, php, objective-c, swift, parse-platform

If I query data with withinMiles = 10 miles and maximum # of returned values = 10, how can I retrieve values that are closest first?

For example, there might be 100 values within 10 miles but I want the closest 10 to return.

Does withinMiles retrieve the closest values first?

Answer (score 2):

The basic steps are as follows:

- Retrieve all values for `withinMiles = 10 miles`
- Sort these values based on distance
- Take the first 10

You really won't find a better method, unless you write a custom method on your database.

Comment: So parse by default returns values randomly? Or is there a default (ie: alphabetical?)

Comment: Well, you'd have to consult their docs about that - I've never used it before.  What I can tell you is that if you want an inherent ordering based on distance, you'll somehow have to have that distance be a primary key/index, but I'm guessing that's not possible, as you're probably basing this off of a temporary position of a user (from gps, I assume?).  If you're able to write database methods, you could do a sort of insertion sort algorithm to insert into a list of ten items (almost like finding the min value of a list, but with more items).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was just curious if I needed to sort the values myself, or if the return values were returned as closest values first.